# For loop over dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

i have dataframe called `df_civic` with columns - `state ,rank, make/model, model year, thefts`. I want to calculate **AVG** and **STD** of `thefts` for each `model year`.

All years that are in dataframe are taken with: `years_civic = list(pd.unique(df_civic['Model Year']))`

My loop looks like this:

```
for civic_year in years_civic:
    f = df_civic['Model Year'] == civic_year
    civic_avg = df_civic[f]['Thefts'].mean()
    civic_std = df_civic[f]['Thefts'].std()
    civic_std= np.round(car_std,2)
    civic_avg= np.round(car_avg,2)
    print(civic_avg, civic_std, np.sum(f))
```

However output is not what i need, only output that is correct is the one from `np.sum(f)`

Now output looks like this:

```
9.0 20.51 1
9.0 20.51 1
9.0 20.51 1
9.0 20.51 1
9.0 20.51 13
9.0 20.51 15
9.0 20.51 3
9.0 20.51 2
```

Comment: Please include sample data and format your question according to tips provided in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305

Comment: @Aleksander, you can use triple ``` code ```, to mark a code block over multiple lines. Took a while to edit your 100s of code blocks and <br>s :) .. Also, you can simple move a new line to another line without using <br>. Its allowed in markdown. Check how I edited your question to format your question better next time. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, sorry i'll use correct ones next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas provides many powerful functions for aggregating your data. It's usually better to first think of these functions before using `for` loops.

For instance, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_civic.groupby("Model Year").agg({"theft": ["mean", np.std]})
```

More doc here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

Regarding your code, there is something weird, `car_std` and `car_avg` are not defined.

Comment: Why hurry? You haven't told the OP where he might be going wrong, and while yours likely a better solution, why offer an untested one?

Comment: @navneethc can you indicate what I'm doing wrong, I'd love to know that as well honestly.

Comment: @AleksanderKuś Can you post sample data?

Comment: I checked the code, loop itself is correct - it's working, I didn't define car_std and car_avg  correctly and it took value from other loop. Thanks guys.